# Execute bulk partial update on solr

Tags: solr

We want to update a field of more than one document without ID being passed. We may need to update 1.5 M documents in one go. It seems to us that executing atomic update specified in https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/updating-parts-of-documents.html#atomic-updates for a field in Solr cluster (8.4.1) is a good way to do that. As specified in https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/updating-parts-of-documents.html#field-storage, we have checked all fields in managed-schema file are having stored = true. We have below questions in regards to that:-

1. Can we try atomic update for updating a field of more than one document without ID being passed? If not, please suggest another way to do this.
2. Do we need to stop the traffic (read and write) while updating a field with atomic update?
3. Whether the atomic update is possible if we want to update 1.5 M documents in one go. Can we execute add, set etc. operations specified in https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/updating-parts-of-documents.html#atomic-updates for the same key value pair for about 1.5 M documents?

Please let us know if we have any doubts.

Best,